# Ruby output contents of an array as a comma separated string Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a more correct way to output the contents of an array as a comma delimited string

```
@emails = ["joe@example.com", "Peter@example.com", "alice@example.com"]

@emails * ","

=> "joe@example.com", "Peter@example.com", "alice@example.com"
```

This works but I am sure there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, the result will be `"joe@example.com,Peter@example.com,alice@example.com"`

Comment: I'm confused: what's inelegant about `array_name * ","`?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
@emails.join(",")
```

Comment: `join` is an alias for `*`, so this is just repeating the OP's question.

Comment: But `join` is certainly easier to understand.

Answer (score 16):

Though the OP and many answers imply that the array always has content, sometimes I find myself needing to join a list that may contain "empty" elements (typically for concatenating data for a UI).

Here is little "progression" of how different approaches handle such an "imperfect" array of strings:

```
['a','b','',nil].join(',') # => "a,b,," 
['a','b','',nil].compact.join(',') # => "a,b,"
['a','b','',nil].compact.reject(&:empty?).join(',') # => "a,b"
['a','b','',nil].reject(&:blank?).join(',') # Rails only
```

The last one being my favorite (Rails) approach.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do something similar in an ERB template using 
`AllowedUsers <%= _allowed_users.join(" ") %>`. It might not be as elegant as you were looking for, but it's the same implementation I've seen in several languages, so that might be a win for readability.